# FFMPEG SRT multiple callers in to one listener?

Tags: nginx, ffmpeg

I am using this line:  `exec_push /home/production/bin/ffmpeg -i rtmp://localhost:1935/live/slot4 -codec copy  -g 1  -bsf:v h264_mp4toannexb -f  mpegts srt://0.0.0.0:50330?mode=listener -loglevel verbose;` in nginx to launch FFMPEG and have it transmux RTMP to SRT.  That being said, i'm curious if there is a flag or a way to have multiple SRT callers call into this one stream.  If not, can you provide and alternative solution?

Answer (score -1):

Take a look here: [srt-live-server](https://github.com/Edward-Wu/srt-live-server)
Works very well